# Echoing PHP within HTML

Tags: php, html, echo

I am currently trying to create a shopping cart for my website and I have images of products stored in a database and I want to include them within <`img src>` . By putting `$get_row[imagesrc]` within the src. I need to know the correct way to add it to the below code as I dont fully understand the `'` and `.` tags

```
    echo '<p>'.$get_row['name'].'<br/>'.$get_row['description'].'<br/>'.$get_row['imagesrc'].
'<br/>&pound;'.number_format($get_row['price'],2).'<a href="cart.php?add='.$get_row['id'].'">Add</a></p>';
```

Comment: You will really get mad in generating html this way - get into some templating engine like Smarty or Twig.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should achieve what you're looking for:

```
echo '<p>'.$get_row['name'].'<br/>'.$get_row['description'].'<br/><img src="'.$get_row['imagesrc'].'" /><br/>&pound;'.number_format($get_row['price'],2).'<a href="cart.php?add='.$get_row['id'].'">Add</a></p>';
```

The `'` character defines a string literal when it is wrapped around a series of characters.
The `.` character is used for concatenating strings for output or storage.

Answer (score 2):

```
echo '<p>'.$get_row['name'].'<br/>'.$get_row['description'].'<br/><img src="'.$get_row['imagesrc'].'"><br/>&pound;'.number_format($get_row['price'],2).'<a href="cart.php?add='.$get_row['id'].'">Add</a></p>';
```

Answer (score 2):

. concatenates two strings, and ' is wrapped around a string.

so

```
echo 'Hello '.'World'; // Shows Hello World
```

I'd split yours up to make it easier to read:

```
echo '<p>';
    echo $get_row['name'].'<br/>';
    echo $get_row['description'].'<br/>';
    echo '<img src="'.$get_row['imagesrc'].'" /><br/>';
    echo '&pound;'.number_format($get_row['price'],2);
    echo '<a href="cart.php?add='.$get_row['id'].'">Add</a>';
echo '</p>';
```

But it all looks OK.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo '<p>'.$get_row['name'].'<br/>
<img src="'.$get_row['imagesrc'].'" alt="'.$get_row['name'].'"><br/>
<br/>&pound;'.number_format($get_row['price'],2).'
<a href="cart.php?add='.$get_row['id'].'">Add</a></p>';`
```

Answer (score 1):

```
echo '<img src="'.$get_row['imagesrc'].'">';
```

Try that.

Answer (score 1):

A [specific answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14200753/164998) has been given:

```
echo '<img src="'.$get_row['imagesrc'].'">';
```

Nonetheless, it's worth adding that you should:

- You should escape output - with [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) or otherwise.

  ```
  echo '<img src="' . htmlspecialchars($get_row['imagesrc']) . '">';
  ```
- Read the documentation on [PHP Strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php).

Answer (score 1):

Check out this way of including PHP in your HTML. It's much easier to read and maintain. The last line in the paragraph is your image tag.

```
<p>
    <?php echo $get_row['name']; ?><br/>
    <?php echo $get_row['description']; ?><br/>
    <?php echo $get_row['imagesrc']; ?><br/>
    &pound;<?php echo number_format($get_row['price'],2); ?>
    <a href="cart.php?add=<?php echo $get_row['id']; ?>">Add</a>
    <img src="<?php echo $get_row['imagesrc']; ?>" />
</p>
```